# How can I find the elements appearing  in two columns of a tab-delimited file?

Tags: perl

I have a file which is tab delimited, and has two columns, A and B.

I want to count the number of times an element in B is repeated in A. I could have done it in Excel, but since the two columns contain more than 200k elements, it hangs.

I tried with this code but it counts elements in itself:

```
    my %counts = ();
    for (@A) {
    $count{$_}++;
    }

    foreach my $k(keys %counts) {
     print "$k\t$count{$k}\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %countx;
my @y;

my $file = 'ab.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Couldn't open $file";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line; # remove newline

    # I've avoided using $a and $b because they are special variables in perl
    my ( $x, $y ) = split /\t/, $line;

    $countx{ $x }++;
    push @y, $y;
}
close $fh;

foreach my $y (@y) {
    my $count = $countx{ $y } || 0;
    print "$y\t$count\n";
}
```

Comment: You don't want to split on whitespace. Split only on tabs. The other whitespace may be significant.